# unity remote 4 app not working in windows/android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I installed the **unity remote 4** app in my android phone (Lollipop OS).
When i click play option in unity editor it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your Unity version?

Comment: unity 5.1.3f   pretty old version i also checked with the new version too it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Unity Remote 4` does not work for you, download `Unity Remote 5`. It fixed problems such as not connecting. In order to use `Unity Remote 5`, you must download `Unity 5.4` and above.

From Unity Editor, go to 
**Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Editor** then chose your device(Android) from the device drop down menu.

Sometimes, you have to restart Adb in order to get it to start working. To do that, open the `Task Manager`, go into the `Processes` tab, select `Adb (32 bit)` under `Background Processes` then click the `End Task` button.

You can also stop Adb through the `Command Prompt` with `adb kill-server` then start it again with `adb start-server`.