# Can't connect Unity Remote 5 to unity (version 2018.2.3f1)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

I'm trying to connect my Android phone, Huawei p smart, (operating system is Oreo 8.0) to my MacBook Pro. I'm using Unity 2018.2.3f1. I have been to **Edit > Project Settings > Editor** and setting the device to **Any Android Device**. 
When I press play, nothing happens. I have also been on my phone to the developer's settings and set **USB Debugging** on. Nothing works. I have been all around the internet searching. Nothing I find seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803359/unity-remote-4-app-not-working-in-windows-android/39807887#39807887)

Comment: I can't find the Task manager on my mac.

Comment: On Mac you don't need Task manager. Use the [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084766/how-to-restart-android-adb-using-terminal-on-macos) to kill and restart adb. Note that you must have Android SDK to do this and you must also set it up in the Editor

Comment: I have downloaded Android SDK. But I can't figure out how to "set it up in the Editor". When I try to kill the adb in the Terminal it says: 
-bash: kill: adb: arguments must be process or job IDs

Answer (score 2):

Change wiring from mobile to mac.

- Did not work: Direct connection from USB-C to USB-C
- Did work: Using a USB-C to USB-A adapter inbetween. (Female USB-A part must be on the computer side)

In my case (MacBook pro to Xiaomi Mi A1) it helped.

Explanation:
After connecting the mobile to the mac one should see a notification that the usb connection was established ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maTNI8d9xCY)). This was not the case for me. So I gave it a try and changed the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1259457/view.html) link, follow these steps:

- In Unity, leave enabled the option at “Unity Remote Editor Settings> Device> Any Android Device”
- Close Unity.
- Open Unity Remote App on your Android device.
- Connect your device to your computer.
- Open Unity again.

it's working for me too!
I hope this helps you :)